# Seeing the error with ajaxcontroltoolkit ajaxfileupload data import and update panel for ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: javascript, c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0

The upload and data import functions correctly on the development server, but gets stuck on the "file uploaded" status on the production server.  The correct result is to run some code after the file has been uploaded to the server and then display "The files(s) have been uploaded." in a separate green label.  I am currently using the following code to display certain errors for the code for the data import to the database, but it does not display why the data import gets stuck on the "file uploaded" status.  I think I have isolated where the data import code stops executing, but again, the code should be correct because it functions correctly on the development server.  Is there another way for me to see the error or why the data import code is not being executed?

```
    if (_errMsg != string.Empty)
    {
        successLabel.Visible = false;
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + _errMsg + "');</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", script, false);
    }
    else
    {
        successLabel.Visible = true;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The point at where the data import code stops functioning is related to the following function where the

MainTableChangesUpdateRecord(cwtsData, modifiedBy, Convert.ToInt16(cwtsData[0])).ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being an issue with the database itself such as the database being corrupted and not an issue with the code.  The database was restored to a previous version and everything executed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your code in a try catch block, but I suspect on the Production server you have some restrictions on where the file can be uploaded to i.e. trying to save to 'C' drive when the drive doesn't have write permissions to the root directory.

Comment: I did try a try catch block related to the section where I posted in the update above where the data import code stopped functioning, but I wasn't able to get an error to be displayed.  The file is shown as saved to the production server folder in the website directory as expected and it looks like the data is being read into the variables in the code from the excel file.

Comment: Has the production server got the correct .Net Framework installed